# "Show 1 more comment" opens a new comment textarea instead of showing 1 more comment

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

Repro steps:

1. go to
   [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903482/javascript-compare-two-arrayskey-value-pairs-and-copy-value-from-one-to-the-ot/18903612?noredirect=1#comment27906225_18903612)
   question, find my answer
2. see **"add / show 1 more comment"** link
3. click it

Expected: one more comment shows up **and** textarea appears

Actual: text area for the new comment appears

Is it a bug?

I'm on Win8.1 (maybe that's the problem?) + Chrome29

Comment: No repro.  It shows the text area for the new comment, but it also shows the 1 hidden comment.

Comment: I was able to repro. Probably not a bug. You misread: "**add** / show 1 more comment" is what it says, so it's meant to show 1 more comment in addition to opening the add comment box.

Comment: norepro here too. Browser/OS?

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise enough. Agreed that it's "add/show", but shouldn't I see the comment? Updated the question.

Comment: You don't? Again, please specify your browser and OS

Comment: Ah, nevermind then. I was not able to repro. Both comment and comment box showed up.

Comment: "add / show 1 more comment" -> click -> reveals 1 hidden comment & textarea to comment

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the problem: that happens only when I'm on **Win8.1 Preview** + Chrome29

Comment: The OS shouldn't have any effect. Also, it may be your network. It shows the textarea before showing the comment, but the comment is retrieved using AJAX, so if your configuration isn't working or has a bug where AJAX doesn't work, that would cause the issue.

Comment: I don't think that's because of AJAX. If I click only once after textarea shows up, the last comment never appears. Why don't you think that's because of the OS which still might be not stable enough?

Comment: Well, SE has a long-standing policy of not supporting beta or pre-release software, so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey happens to me as well, with the stable release of Chrome / Win7

Comment: @JanDvorak: That's what I have.

Comment: Stable doesn't mean current. What _versions_ do you have?

Comment: @ColeJohnson 29.0.1547.66 m. Hold on, an update has just arrived.

Comment: @ColeJohnson just updated to 29.0.1547.76 m. I doubt there's going to be a difference.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8 and it still does it, like @ColeJohnson pointed out, it is not OS related. The issue is a bit annoying though.